# Rendering of ASP.NET application when installed on server (asp:Menu and Ajax not working)

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, asp.net-ajax

I've developed a website in ASP.NET with .NET 4.0 using the AJAX control toolkit and it works fine on my local IIS but when I install it on the production server (it's a Windows Server 2008 with IIS 7) it doesn't render properly (in any browser)... I have an asp Menu that doesn't render as it should (the options don't show on mouseover and it's vertical and it should be horizontal) and none of the AJAX controls work (update panel and modal popups)... I've been trying everything and I haven't had any luck so far, so if you guys have any idea please help...Thanks...

Comment: What kind of asp project is it - web site or web application? Which menu control is it? asp:menu isn't actually part of the AJAX toolkit, it's part of the main web controls library that ships with the framework (it's in System.Web.UI.WebControls). Are you sure you have deployed all of your dependencies. Not enough detail, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have some reference path problems. Start up Fiddler (or Firebug, IE Dev Tools, etc) and see if you are getting any 404 errors when trying to load JS or CSS files.

Comment: Thank you so much! I debugged with Firebug and I got the message "ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.". I thought the Ajax framework came with .NET 4.0... Do you think it may have something to do with being Windows Server 2008? I'm going to try and find the framework to install on the server

Comment: Sounds like a configuration/install issue. Try to reinstall or repair the framework and see if that helps.